# Tracing library

Tags: code-analysis, debugging

I need libraries for tracing Java and C++ code (all restricted to using only standard library). In particular I want to record the values of all the variables in memory at every executed line.

For Python, there is Pysnooper but would appreciate if someone knows of a more sophisticated library.

Thanks

Comment: This seems to be two questions in one, one for Java and another for C++, given the vast differences between them.

Comment: Recording "all values" is not realistic for native C++ programs as this would mean to monitor each an every bit of memory as everything can be used as variable. For tracing you could try https://frida.re it contains a tool named `frida-trace` which allows to hook methods and thus trace their arguments and return values. Frida is a framework that allows to run custom JavaScript scripts within the target process and check fields, read arbitrary memory or establish read/write breakpoints on memory regions. It works with Java and native programs on various platforms.